# Getting an input value isn't working?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the value of an input with this :

```
var email = $('form.new-user-form').find('[class=email]').val();
console.log(email);
```

The form is generated with PHP, but I don't think the problem occurs because of that because a few days ago it worked just fine, it looks like this:

```
$form = array(
'<form name="user-count-form" class="user-count-form" method="post" action="#">',
    '<fieldset class="user-count-fields">',
        '<fieldset class="display-count-wrapper">',
            '<label for="display-count" class="display-count-label">Users</label>',
            '<input type="text" name="display-count" class="display-count" value="' . $this->userCount() . '" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" />',
        '</fieldset>',
        '<fieldset class="new-user-wrapper">',
            '<button type="submit" name="new-user" class="new-user">New User</button>',
        '</fieldset>',
    '</fieldset>',
'</form>',
'<form name="new-user-form" class="new-user-form" method="post" action="#">',
    '<fieldset class="new-user-fields">',
        '<fieldset class="email-wrapper">',
            '<label for="email" class="email-label">Email</label>',
            '<input type="email" name="email" class="email" value="" autocomplete="off" />',
        '</fieldset>',
        '<fieldset class="create-wrapper">',
            '<button type="submit" name="create" class="create">Create</button>',
        '</fieldset>',
    '</fieldset>',                         
'</form>',
'<div class="message-handling"></div>'
);
$form = implode("", $form);
echo $form;
```

And all I get in the console is `(an empty string)` either if the input is empty or not. Why is that happening ?

Comment: besides, why not use `$('form.new-user-form input.email').val();`

Comment: Please do not use attribute selectors to select elements by class but `.classname` instead; e.g. `$('form.new-user-form .email')` - that'll be much faster. Besides that: consider using a template engine so you don't have to deal with quotes etc.

Comment: after the DOM is loaded in a script tag at the bottom of the page from constrain reasons ( I'm using jQuery Tools Tabs to load content and that's the only way I can do it )

Comment: Yes, but I have found that using `.find()` works a bit faster, I don't know why, I've read it on some forum and I saw some tests. I'll try using that too, let me see.

Comment: If your class="email" is unique you can use: `var email = $('.email').val();`

Comment: @RomainGUILLAUME It isn't, but now it works again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding quotes around the class value, or use the `.` notation for classes:

```
var email = $('form.new-user-form').find('[class="email"]').val();
console.log(email);
```

or:

```
var email = $('form.new-user-form').find('.email').val();
console.log(email);
```

Comment: Yep, selecting by class using attribute selector do not work neither in jQuery, nor in document.querySelector.

Comment: I've tried all before posting here the question, neither worked.

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log($('form.new-user-form').find('.email').length);` to make sure that the jQuery selector is working?

Comment: @pete I get `1` in the console.

Comment: @pete for some reason after using your suggestion I've tried getting the value again in all ways possible and it works each time, I'm not sure why but I would like to find out

Comment: @Alex I've found a bug in how I tested it. Element has 2 classes. Of course, this didn't work for selector with only one class.